# Inspect Element and data security

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a message system, where the user logged in (UserA) will insert a username inside a search box and it will return a result(UserB, if any).

If there is a result, UserA will be able to send a message to UserB.

The way i did it, was:

1) stored the ID of userA and userB inside an HTML element (Ex. hidden field)

2) accessed these values using JavaScript and DOM

3) sent these values over to a PHP script (using AJAX), which is responsible to send the message to UserB

The problem is that if i use "Inspect Element" on my page, i can see/alter the value of the sender(UserA) or/and receiver(UserB) ID. This way any one can send a message as another user, if he changes the value of the ID of userA.

Is there another way to do this? Do i have to send the values using sessions to the PHP script directly?

Thanks

Comment: the `from:` id should come from session.

Comment: That's what i thought. But if i can send every data i need over to the other PHP script using sessions, why even bother accessing values from DOM using jQuery/JavaScript? ps: i am sending data over SSL.

Comment: erm how can you send user generated datas through session?

Comment: i am wondering about the same thing like `itachi`. a `PHP` session is user-based and afaik it's not possible to access data across multiple sessions.

Comment: As soon as the result of the search come back, i will store the ID of the receiver to a session ( $_SESSION['rID'] = $rID ), and send it to PHP script along with the ID of the sender.  Is this wrong?

Comment: _“But if i can send every data i need over to the other PHP script using sessions, why even bother accessing values from DOM using jQuery/JavaScript?”_ – well you tell us … it’s your mangeld approach after all, so we can’t know what made you chose it in the first place.

Comment: So to recap: if an information can be send in both ways (sessions and DOM) i should use sessions?